# Banner <div> wont show in IE9, but does show in Chrome

Tags: css, html, internet-explorer-9

So I have a banner div under my navigation, however the banner seems to be showing up in Google Chrome, but doesn't show up in IE9. The HTML and CSS are below.

HTML:

```html
<div class="content">       
    <div class="slide-banner"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```css
.slide-banner {
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0px;
    width: 650px;
    height: 200px;
    background: #ff0000;
}
```

EDIT:

After trying all the suggestions made by everyone, I figured it wasn't my actual code, it may be an issue with my browser itself. so I ran the code on 2 other PC's with IE9 and it seems to work fine. Thanks for everyone help, much appreciated!

Comment: can you create a jsfiddle that demonstrates this? It seems to be working fine for me in IE9... http://jsfiddle.net/bqvJh/

Answer (score 0):

First thing I do in these situations where I know things should work but they aren't is to validate. A lot of times I have missed a tag somewhere and something isn't closed like it should be.

Other than that, try adding a display:block to the .slide-banner class. If that doesn't work... put a little text in there or add an image. http://placehold.it/650x200